# Attribute <input type="email"> doesn't validate properly in HTML5

Tags: php, html, validation, input

I have been using HTML5's new input types for easier validation. I have noticed a problem (tested on Chrome, but not sure about other browsers) that doesn't make much sense. If I was to place michael in my email field it will come up saying that it needs to be a valid email, fantastic, but when I try michael@test and don't have the extension, it validates properly.

What I would like to know is, is this a bug or done on purpose?

I would also like to point this problem out to people who use it in the future and think it works 100%.

Fortunately I run Laravel's own email check which works perfectly, but why wouldn't Chrome or anyone at the W3 Consortium not know of this problem? It could be quite a risk to rely on this 100% and thinking that people are using valid email addresses from this input type.

Comment: I think they do this because if you host your own website and you make an email adres it will most likely be something like info@domeinname.com or what ever. The best thing you could do is use php to validate email or like you said use something like Laravel

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`michael@test` **is** a valid email address in that it is formatted in a valid manner. A valid email address naturally does not mean that the email address is able to receive messages or that your mail daemon can even send messages to it.

[The W3C working group note on input type=email](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.email.html) says that the match criteria is any string that matches the following regular expression:

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&’*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/
```

Thus, `^_^"@666.42.99-` is also considered a valid email address by that criteria, though the host part of the address is clearly invalid.

Unfortunately, there is no other way to positively and conclusively verify the validity of an email address but a send a verification message there and ask for user action based on the content of that message.

The HTML 5 validation is still pretty good at ensuring that you did not type your telephone number or address by accident in the email field; but any client data should always be considered possibly invalid and untrusted and rechecked at the server side anyway.

Comment: Fantastic answer, thank you so much. I will always use server side validation as secondary and a confirmation where necessary, but I do like HTML's email validation and like you said, it does come in handy for users. I just hope there are people out there who won't be just relying on this as their only validation method.